# Tensor contractions in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have numpy arrays of the shape:(2000, 3) (3, 2000, 2). I am wondering if the following tensor contraction:

```
t1 = np.einsum("ij,jik->ik", a, b)
```

can be done using `np.dot`. I have tried to do:

```
  out = np.zeros((2000, 2))
  for k in range(2):
      out[:, k] = np.dot(a, b[:, :, k])
```

but it throws an error:
*ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1000,1000) into shape (1000)*

Iterating over the first dimension (i) seems not to be very efficient.

Comment: iterate on `i,  2000, since the `dot` sum-of-products is on `j`.  `k` isn't shared.  `matmul` can do it without a loop, but will require transpose and dimension addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a minimal example (which we like to see in questions):

```
In [173]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3); b=np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,2)
In [174]: t1 = np.einsum('ij,jik->ik', a, b)
In [175]: t1.shape
Out[175]: (4, 2)
In [176]: t1
Out[176]: 
array([[ 40,  43],
       [136, 148],
       [268, 289],
       [436, 466]])
```

The working loop, iteration on `i` (yes, even though it may be large)

```
In [177]: out = np.zeros((4,2),int)
In [178]: for i in range(4):
     ...:     out[i,:] = np.dot(a[i], b[:,i,:])
     ...: 
In [179]: out
Out[179]: 
array([[ 40,  43],
       [136, 148],
       [268, 289],
       [436, 466]])
```

It has to work before we worry about efficiency!

Now if we transpose `b` we can change the `einsum` to:

```
In [181]: np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik', a, b.transpose(1,0,2)).shape
Out[181]: (4, 2)
```

With `j` in the right places, `dot` works - but it does an `outer` product on the shared `i` dimension.  We'd have to take its diagonal:

```
In [182]: np.dot( a, b.transpose(1,0,2)).shape
Out[182]: (4, 4, 2)
```

`matmul/@` was added to change this 'outer' behavior to a more common 'batch'.  But we need to add a dimension to `a` so the `i` is first of 3 for all terms:

```
In [184]: np.matmul( a[:,None,:], b.transpose(1,0,2)).shape
Out[184]: (4, 1, 2)
```

and finally squeeze out the 1 dimension:

```
In [186]: np.matmul( a[:,None,:], b.transpose(1,0,2))[:,0,:]
Out[186]: 
array([[ 40,  43],
       [136, 148],
       [268, 289],
       [436, 466]])
```

This last expression should be as fast, if not faster, than the `einsum`.

```
In [192]: timeit t1 = np.einsum('ij,jik->ik', a, b)
8.05 µs ± 63.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [193]: timeit np.matmul( a[:,None,:], b.transpose(1,0,2))[:,0,:]
5.19 µs ± 183 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```